# Android SavePreferences from listview

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save preferences from a ListView, using the following code I can save the value from an EditText:

```
etpref = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpreftest);
SavePreferences("testpr", etpref.getText().toString());
```

then I retrieve it with

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
         .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
         String strtestpr = sp.getString("testpr", null);

if (strtestpr.contains(body)) {
    //do something
}
```

what I need to do is save the value from the items in a ListView and use them in the same way (if that's possible). I konw it's possible to save from individual items/rows from the list using this code but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

What data structure are you using to back your Listview? What adapter type are you using? You should be able to use what ever you need from that adapter? If it's an ArrayAdapter for example, every time the user edits something in your list, you should immediately save the new value back to your array. That way you can retrieve them when ever you want.

As far as storing them in a shared preference, you can't really store arrays in a SharedPreferences. Your best bet is to probably save them into a database. You could however use [putStringSet()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) if you don't care about the order the strings are stored in, or if they map to anything.

Comment: im using sqlite. the app is almost finished, what i need is to be able to check the content of the listview and if the current string equels or contains any of the values in the rows of the listview then do somthing (hope that makes sence).. its the user that populates the listview so it may have 1 item or 100

Comment: i dont care about the order there stored in, im still very new to this and not really sure how i would go about using putStringSet() do you know of any working examples of this?

Comment: I don't know of any examples. But this is something that's pretty simple. Are you just not familiar with sets or something?

Comment: no im not, like I said im still very new, looking into putStringSet() is that just for 3.0 and above? im targeting 2.2

Comment: Yea, looks like that's only for 3.0 and above. So you'll have to store the stuff persistently in a database.